# Adding numbers with like bases and variable exponents

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If I have $2^{M+1} + 2^{M+1}$ how do I add this? I know the result is $2^{M+2}$ but how is this achieved?

Do I factor out a $2$ for example:

$$2(2^M + 2^M)$$

But that doesn't really get me anywhere.

Comment: $2^M + 2^M = 2 \cdot 2^M$.

Comment: Oh wow, that was so simple. Thank you so much!

Comment: you are welcome my friend

Answer (score 2):

$2^{m+1}+2^{m+1}=2*2^{m+1}$

which  is clearly  $2^{m+2}$  because $2*2^{x}=2^{x+1}$

Answer (score 1):

As $\square+\square=2\cdot\square$ we have $2^{M+1}+2^{M+1}=2\cdot2^{M+1}$. That equals $2^{M+2}$.